# using data-table for listing with select/selectall rows for rows selection by script, then how can i set/get dynamic ids of selected rows

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, datatable, datatables

I am using data-table for listing & using data-table row select functionality with scripting..

My code snippet:

```
<table id="conf_table">
</table>
```

Script for selectall/select-multiple rows:

```
<script>
    let example = $('#conf_table').DataTable({
    columnDefs: [{
        orderable: false,
        className: 'select-checkbox',
        targets: 0
    }],
    select: {
        style: 'multi',
        selector: 'td:first-child'
    },
    order: [
        [0, 'asc']
    ]
});
example.on("click", "th.select-checkbox", function() { 
    if ($("th.select-checkbox").hasClass("selected")) { 
        example.rows().deselect();
        $("th.select-checkbox").removeClass("selected");
    } else { 
        example.rows().select();
        $("th.select-checkbox").addClass("selected");
    }
}).on("select deselect", function() {
    ("Some selection or deselection going on")
    if (example.rows({ 
            selected: true
        }).count() !== example.rows().count()) {
        $("th.select-checkbox").removeClass("selected");
    } else { 
        $("th.select-checkbox").addClass("selected");
    }
});

</script>
```

And when i inspect selected rows's checkbox then its showing code like..

```
.....
<tr class="gradeX odd selected" role="row">
 <td class="select-checkbox sorting_1">
  ::before
  ::after
 </td>
</tr>
....
```

Now how can i set dynamic row ids with foreach & how can get it in post??

please suggest me changes??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very simple way to set a dynamic id for each row:

```
var n=0;
$('tr').each(function() {
    n++;
    $(this).attr('id', n);
});
```

... is this what you mean to do? Also what do you mean by 'get it in post'? Needs some clarification on what you're trying to achieve.